# WSO2 ESB Preserve Payload Message

Tags: soap, wso2-esb

I have the below proxy service which is being called by a proxy service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="seq_invchk_slpa_in" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <log level="custom">
    <property name="STATUS::" value="***************************"/>
  </log>
  <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:hnb="http://10.104.74.93/hnb"
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
          <hnb:CheckInvoiceDetails soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <invoice_no xsi:type="xsd:string">$1</invoice_no>
          </hnb:CheckInvoiceDetails>
        </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
    </format>
    <args>
      <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:invoice_no"/>
    </args>
  </payloadFactory>
  <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
  <header name="Action" scope="default" value="CheckInvoiceDetails"/>
  <property name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="CheckInvoiceDetails"/>
  <send>
    <endpoint key="gov:INVCHK/SLPA/endpoints/invchk_slpa_validation_ep.xml"/>
  </send>
</sequence>
```

When calling from a tool (SOAP UI) the service works without any problem.

But when calling from a system an issue arises. what I have traced out so far
is during the correct call the payload factory message is sent as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hnb="http://10.104.74.93/hnb" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hnb:CheckInvoiceDetails soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <invoice_no xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" xsi:type="xsd:string">17231374967185</invoice_no>
      </hnb:CheckInvoiceDetails>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When the erroneous call is made the payload message goes out of the ESB as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hnb:CheckInvoiceDetails xmlns:hnb="http://10.104.74.93/hnb" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <invoice_no xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">17231374967185</invoice_no>
</hnb:CheckInvoiceDetails>
```

which  I think causes the issue. The response i get from the client during the erroneous call is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap .org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">Operation '' is not defined in the WSDL for  this service</faultstring>
         <detail xsi:type="xsd:string" />
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I preserve the SOAP message as it is and send it out when being called by a system.

Why are the soap namespaces getting mixed up in the 
method level 
`<hnb:CheckInvoiceDetails xmlns:hnb="http://10.104.74.93/hnb" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">`

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Save it in property <property name="OriginalMessage" expression="$body/*" type="OM" />. Then restore when u need using enrich.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but while sending the message changes, that's the problem, any clue on why the soap name spaces are being added?

Comment: PayloadFactory mediator is desinged to change content of message body. Why do you have envelope, header, and body tags. WSOESB will add envelope to message itself before transmit message through transport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You at least have to change content of Payload Factory mediator to

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
          <hnb:CheckInvoiceDetails xmlns:hnb="http://10.104.74.93/hnb">
            <hnb:invoice_no xsi:type="xsd:string">$1</hnb:invoice_no>
          </hnb:CheckInvoiceDetails>
    </format>
    <args>
      <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:invoice_no"/>
    </args>
  </payloadFactory>
```

pay attention to invoice_no tag. Originally it is not clear what a namespace it suppose to have, it actually nest namespace of synapse engine, by default. So better to assign namespace explicitly.

Synapse engine will add envelope by default.

**If a message type is unknown this returns soap12.** found in documentation of Synapse. 
Property Content-Type without messageType is useless.

Comment: By default the synapse engine will add the SOAP 1.2 headers, what if I need 1.1 headers, how can I add them explicitly?

Comment: I have no chance to check it right now. But I remember when u create SOAP project in SOAPUI of service on ESB u will get 2 copies of service. one works on soap1.1 another on soap1.2

Comment: Let say service name SampleProxy then you will get 2 copies of each endpoint of every transport type u assign for service. For soap u will get 
http://ip-address:port/services/SampleProxy.SoapEnpoint1.1
http://ip-address:port/services/SampleProxy.SoapEnpoint1.2
Try to use correct address

Comment: "If a message type is unknown this returns soap12. found in documentation of Synapse. Property Content-Type without messageType is useless. ", this is absolutely correct and was helpful in overcoming the issue, Thanks a lot for you time :)